# Check whether section/subsection is longer than one page

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, cross-referencing

I have defined myself a small (probably disgustingly overcomplicated) command to reference parts of my document and add the respective page number to the output if the referenced part is on a different page:

```
\newcommand{\myautoref}[1]{
  \hyperref[#1]{\autoref{#1}\ifthenelse{\thepage=\pageref{#1}}{}{ on page \pageref{#1}}}
}
```

(I know that ifthen is considered to be obsolete and I have tried using `etoolbox` instead of `ifthen` but couldn't get it to work.)

This commands works just the way I want it to work but it would be even better if it would say something like "from page X onwards" instead of "on page X" when the referenced (sub)section/chapter/whatever is more than one page long. Is there a way to do that without having to add a second label at the end of every section?

Comment: How should latex know that the section is longer than one page?

Comment: AFAIK  although hyperlinks can badly jump to odd places in 4D they are primordially 1D (to one specific named destination) thus generally have no concept of 2D length best you could do is change text to "{ on or from page \pageref{#1} " to infinity and beyond" :-)}} or whatever takes your fancy Once apon a time, this link to a Galaxy far far away

Comment: you are missing `%` at the ends of lines in that definition so you will get spurious extra space in the output.  you need a second label, or perhaps simpler a version of teh command that takes two arguments the label of this section and the so you can use the "main" section labels rather than having to have extra ones. then you can test whether the next section starts on the same page

Comment: @DavidCarlisle thanks for pointing that out. I'll add the %s. This is a little disappointing but thanks you guys for your help :)

Comment: What do you mean by "disappointing"? If latex knows where all the sections begin it could naturally test for their length, but you haven't given any info yet if your document contains the necessary structure.

Comment: how would you expect to be able to tell a single page section _without_ comparing two labels?

Comment: In any case you should be using \getpagerefnumber (hyperref or refcount).  \pageref is protected and cannot be used for anything except display.

Comment: @JohnKormylo `ifthenelse` takes care of that. (the author is so kind:-)

Comment: @UlrikeFischer well, Latex does know where a new heading is placed. (At least in my document) every heading marks the beginning of another section. Latex could check whether there is another heading below the referenced one but on the same page. That's how I imagine it with my limited Latex knowledge at least

Comment: Even if the next heading is on the next page, this doesn't imply that the current section is longer than one page. And just to be a bit more explicit: I won't build a test document from your snippet with all possible variants to answer your question, that is your job.